# How to convert floodplain inundation results from a Hec-Ras model into Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, google-earth, hec-ras

Having run a Hec-Ras 4.1.0 model, I wish to show the results in Google Earth. How is this possible and is it possible to do this by using ArcMap 10.1?

Comment: Which results do you want to show (Raster flood depths or just extent polygon)? Have you already imported the results into Arc (this can be involved and there are tools available to help)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data to KML. In ArcToolbox under Conversion Tools there are two tools in To KML. Try those.